# Building LLVM using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake, llvm

I'm trying to build LLVM using visual studio 2012 (version 10.0). I have CMake installed and have run the following commands:

1. svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk llvm
2. cd llvm\tools
3. svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk clang
4. cd ....
5. mkdir build
6. cd build
7. cmake -G "Visual Studio 10" ..\llvm

Running these commands works fine, until the last step. I receive a large number of warnings(?) which are as follows:

```
-- Looking for dirent.h
-- Looking for dirent.h - not found
-- Looking for dlfcn.h
-- Looking for dlfcn.h - not found
-- Looking for errno.h
-- Looking for errno.h - found
-- Looking for execinfo.h
-- Looking for execinfo.h - not found
-- Looking for fcntl.h
-- Looking for fcntl.h - found
-- Looking for inttypes.h
-- Looking for inttypes.h - not found
-- Looking for limits.h
-- Looking for limits.h - found
-- Looking for link.h
-- Looking for link.h - not found
-- Looking for malloc.h
-- Looking for malloc.h - found
-- Looking for malloc/malloc.h
-- Looking for malloc/malloc.h - not found
-- Looking for ndir.h
-- Looking for ndir.h - not found
-- Looking for signal.h
-- Looking for signal.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for sys/dir.h
-- Looking for sys/dir.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/ioctl.h
-- Looking for sys/ioctl.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/mman.h
-- Looking for sys/mman.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/ndir.h
-- Looking for sys/ndir.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/param.h
-- Looking for sys/param.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/resource.h
-- Looking for sys/resource.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/stat.h
-- Looking for sys/stat.h - found
-- Looking for sys/time.h
-- Looking for sys/time.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/uio.h
-- Looking for sys/uio.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/wait.h
-- Looking for sys/wait.h - not found
-- Looking for termios.h
-- Looking for termios.h - not found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - not found
-- Looking for utime.h
-- Looking for utime.h - not found
-- Looking for valgrind/valgrind.h
-- Looking for valgrind/valgrind.h - not found
-- Looking for zlib.h
-- Looking for zlib.h - not found
-- Looking for fenv.h
-- Looking for fenv.h - not found
-- Looking for FE_ALL_EXCEPT
-- Looking for FE_ALL_EXCEPT - not found
-- Looking for FE_INEXACT
-- Looking for FE_INEXACT - not found
-- Looking for mach/mach.h
-- Looking for mach/mach.h - not found
-- Looking for mach-o/dyld.h
-- Looking for mach-o/dyld.h - not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXXABI_H
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXXABI_H - Failed
-- Looking for arc4random
-- Looking for arc4random - not found
-- Looking for backtrace
-- Looking for backtrace - not found
-- Looking for getpagesize
-- Looking for getpagesize - not found
-- Looking for getrusage
-- Looking for getrusage - not found
-- Looking for setrlimit
-- Looking for setrlimit - not found
-- Looking for isatty
-- Looking for isatty - not found
-- Looking for isinf
-- Looking for isinf - not found
-- Looking for isinf
-- Looking for isinf - not found
-- Looking for finite
-- Looking for finite - not found
-- Looking for isnan
-- Looking for isnan - not found
-- Looking for isnan
-- Looking for isnan - not found
-- Looking for ceilf
-- Looking for ceilf - found
-- Looking for floorf
-- Looking for floorf - found
-- Looking for fmodf
-- Looking for fmodf - found
-- Looking for log
-- Looking for log - found
-- Looking for log2
-- Looking for log2 - not found
-- Looking for log10
-- Looking for log10 - found
-- Looking for exp
-- Looking for exp - found
-- Looking for exp2
-- Looking for exp2 - not found
-- Looking for exp10
-- Looking for exp10 - not found
-- Looking for futimens
-- Looking for futimens - not found
-- Looking for futimes
-- Looking for futimes - not found
-- Looking for nearbyintf
-- Looking for nearbyintf - not found
-- Looking for mallinfo
-- Looking for mallinfo - not found
-- Looking for malloc_zone_statistics
-- Looking for malloc_zone_statistics - not found
-- Looking for mkdtemp
-- Looking for mkdtemp - not found
-- Looking for mkstemp
-- Looking for mkstemp - not found
-- Looking for mktemp
-- Looking for mktemp - not found
-- Looking for closedir
-- Looking for closedir - not found
-- Looking for opendir
-- Looking for opendir - not found
-- Looking for readdir
-- Looking for readdir - not found
-- Looking for getcwd
-- Looking for getcwd - not found
-- Looking for gettimeofday
-- Looking for gettimeofday - not found
-- Looking for getrlimit
-- Looking for getrlimit - not found
-- Looking for posix_spawn
-- Looking for posix_spawn - not found
-- Looking for pread
-- Looking for pread - not found
-- Looking for realpath
-- Looking for realpath - not found
-- Looking for sbrk
-- Looking for sbrk - not found
-- Looking for srand48
-- Looking for srand48 - not found
-- Looking for strtoll
-- Looking for strtoll - not found
-- Looking for strtoq
-- Looking for strtoq - not found
-- Looking for strerror
-- Looking for strerror - found
-- Looking for strerror_r
-- Looking for strerror_r - not found
-- Looking for strerror_s
-- Looking for strerror_s - found
-- Looking for setenv
-- Looking for setenv - not found
-- Looking for _chsize_s
-- Looking for _chsize_s - found
-- Looking for _alloca
-- Looking for _alloca - not found
-- Looking for __alloca
-- Looking for __alloca - not found
-- Looking for __chkstk
-- Looking for __chkstk - not found
-- Looking for ___chkstk
-- Looking for ___chkstk - not found
-- Looking for __ashldi3
-- Looking for __ashldi3 - not found
-- Looking for __ashrdi3
-- Looking for __ashrdi3 - not found
-- Looking for __divdi3
-- Looking for __divdi3 - not found
-- Looking for __fixdfdi
-- Looking for __fixdfdi - not found
-- Looking for __fixsfdi
-- Looking for __fixsfdi - not found
-- Looking for __floatdidf
-- Looking for __floatdidf - not found
-- Looking for __lshrdi3
-- Looking for __lshrdi3 - not found
-- Looking for __moddi3
-- Looking for __moddi3 - not found
-- Looking for __udivdi3
-- Looking for __udivdi3 - not found
-- Looking for __umoddi3
-- Looking for __umoddi3 - not found
-- Looking for __main
-- Looking for __main - not found
-- Looking for __cmpdi2
-- Looking for __cmpdi2 - not found
-- Looking for __GLIBC__
-- Looking for __GLIBC__ - not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_INT64_T
-- Performing Test HAVE_INT64_T - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_UINT64_T
-- Performing Test HAVE_UINT64_T - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_U_INT64_T
-- Performing Test HAVE_U_INT64_T - Failed
-- Looking for __atomic_fetch_add_4 in atomic
-- Looking for __atomic_fetch_add_4 in atomic - not found
-- Performing Test LLVM_HAS_ATOMICS
-- Performing Test LLVM_HAS_ATOMICS - Success
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_NO_VARIADIC_MACROS_FLAG
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_NO_VARIADIC_MACROS_FLAG - Failed
-- Target triple: i686-pc-win32
-- Native target architecture is X86
-- Looking for _strtoi64
-- Looking for _strtoi64 - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_ELMCB_PCSTR
-- Performing Test HAVE_ELMCB_PCSTR - Success
-- Threads enabled.
-- Doxygen disabled.
-- Sphinx disabled.
-- Go bindings disabled.
CMake Error at cmake/modules/HandleLLVMOptions.cmake:41 (message):
  Host Visual Studio must be at least 2012 (MSVC 17.0)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:318 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Scratch/Clang/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Scratch/Clang/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

These files are present on my system under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include. The command has completed but has not produced the LLVM.sln file that the documentation tells me should be created.

Could someone advise how to correct the problems that I am encountering? I appreciate whatever guidance you can offer.

Comment: Isn't "Visual Studio 10" "Visual Studio 2010" rather than 2012? 2012 should be 11, and 2013 should be 12. Also I believe that LLVM does require VS2012 or maybe VS2013 by now. They've been pretty aggressive moving up to new versions because they really want to use C++11/C++14 features and VS support is the main thing that holds them back.

Comment: @bames53 Yep, that was part of my problem. Too much time in Linux land :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put Visual Studio on your path.  There's a batch file `vcvars32.bat` (for 32-bit compiles) or `vcvars64.bat` (for 64-bit compiles) you must run from the command line before you invoke CMake.  That sets up all the path and other environment variables so that the compiler is "visible."

On your system, they are in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat
```

and

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\vcvars64.bat
```

Comment: Thanks librik, I'm running the script right now, still getting some missing files but they're POSIX files that aren't listed in the prerequisites. It looks like the problem may have been a reconfiguration that meant I was targeting the wrong version of Visual Studio, which the script corrected. Looks like it's worked this time, I'll try and build the project them update you once I' done.

Comment: Thanks mate, this corrected my toolchain and got things working.

Comment: How do you run the batch file? I'm running into the same exact problem.

Comment: Start up a Command Prompt, use CD to navigate to the directory where the batch file is installed (will depend on what version of Visual Studio you have, 10.0 means VS2010), and then just type "vcvars32.bat" or "vcvars64.bat"

Comment: Ok Im using VS 2013 and followed your answer and comment, but nothing seemed to work. I navigated to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64, ran vcvarsamd64_x86.bat in the command prompt, set the target to Visual Studio 12 Win64 with native defaults in CMake, but got the same results. Could it be I'm overlooking at step somewhere?

Comment: Turns out that the files that are missing that it is looking for is missing from the Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/crt/src and VC/include folders

Answer (score 2):

The cmake visual studio 10 driver is for visual studio 2010. http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/generator/Visual%20Studio%2010%202010.html

LLVM and clang require a compiler that can do most c++11 things.